# An example of set with a countably infinite set of accumulation points

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

I have to give An example of set with a countably infinite set of accumulation points, and I say:

We can consider the set or real numbers and we take an arbitrary real number $x$ then the interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ is infinite and since we can do this with any other real number,hence we have a set with a countably infinite set of accumulation points.

How can I say it more formally or better ?. Thank you :)

Comment: The real interval $]x- \varepsilon, x+ \varepsilon[$ is not countably infinite ; it is uncountably infinite. This is not one of the examples you are looking for ; anything with non-empty interior will have uncountably many limit points.

Comment: thank You @PatrickDaSilva Then which could be a good example? that is not the interval (0,1) or the rational numbers :) thanks

Answer (score 5):

Let $S_{k}=\displaystyle\left\{k+\frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ for every integer $k$. For example, $S_{0}=\displaystyle\left\{\frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ has only one accumulation point, namely $x=0$. In general, the set $S_{k}$ has only one accumulation point, namely $x=k$.

How many accumulation points does the set $S=\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} S_{n}$ have?

Comment: Well we can argue that since each $S_{k}$ has one point of acumulation the union has infinitely points because there are infinitely k isnt it ?

Comment: @user162343: Yes, exactly. The union $S$ has countably infinite set of accumulation points: Indeed, $\{0, 1, 2, 3, …\}$ is the set of accumulation points for the set $S$.

Comment: @user162343: No, wrong. The accumulation points of the union is **not** necessarily the union of the accumulation points! So just because you have a countable sequence of sets each of which has only one accumulation point, does **not** imply that the union of that sequence has countably many accumulation points!

Answer (score 3):

Take any discrete subset $X \subseteq \mathbb R$, that is, for each $x \in X$, there exists $r > 0$ such that $]x-r,x+r[ \, \cap \, X = \{x\}$. For each $x \in X$, choose a sequence $x_n(x) \in ]x-r,x+r[$ such that $x_n(x) \to x$. Then the set
$$
\bigcup_{x \in X} \{ x_n(x) \, | \, n \in \{1,2,\cdots\} \}
$$ 
has limit set point $X$.

Now all you have to do is pick a discrete subset of your choice ($\mathbb N, \mathbb Z$, etc.) and such sequences ($x_n(x) = x + \frac r{2n}$ will always do the trick).

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 2):

$$A = \left\{ m + \frac{1}{n} : m,n \in \mathbb N\right\}$$
The set of accumulation points of this set $A$ is precisely $\mathbb N$.